# João e Maria ajudam-se um ao outro, uma ao outro ou um à outra?

Tags: gramática, concordância-nominal

Não me lembro de alguma vez encontrar as expressões *um à outra* ou *uma ao outro*. Mas serão possíveis ou até mesmo obrigatórias quando o sujeito explícito ou implícito é composto por um substantivo masculino e outro feminino?

De entre as expressões ***um ao outro, um à outra*** e ***uma ao outro***, quais são possíveis nos exemplos seguintes? Se mais do que uma for possível, qual é a mais aconselhável? No caso de *um à outra* e *uma ao outro*, a ordem é importante?

> (a) João e Maria ajudam-se muito ____________
>
> (b) João e Maria são muitos amigos: ajudam-se muito _____________
>
> (c) Conheces o João e a Maria? Eles ajudam-se muito _____________

Comment: Ajudam-se mutuamente. Pronto :)

Comment: Como é que eu não me lembrei dessa! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não estou a ver como é que *um à outra* e *uma ao outro* haviam de ser possíveis.

Em *um ao outro* (ou *uma à outra*), *um* e *outro* não fazem referência a especificamente um dos possíveis sintagmas nominais ("o João" e "a Maria" no teu exemplo); mais do que isso, porque a expressão indica reciprocidade, não podemos interpretar *um* ou *outro* como referindo-se apenas a um dos sintagmas, ainda que indeterminado: *João e Maria ajudam-se um ao outro* significa *João (um) ajuda a Maria (outro)* **e** *Maria (um) ajuda João (outro)*.

Como *uma* e *outra* só podem referir-se a antecedentes femininos, só podem então usar-se quando **todos** os antecedentes são femininos: *A Carla e a Mónica ajudam-se uma à outra*; *A Ana, a Rita e a Gertrudes ajudam-se umas às outras*.

Dito isto, convém não sobreanalisar o pronome recíproco *um ... outro* ao nível dos seus elementos individuais. Por exemplo, uma interpretação possível de *O João, a Maria e a Carla passaram os baldes uns aos outros* é a Carla ter passado os baldes à Maria e a Maria ao João (por exemplo, formavam uma linha). Apesar de apenas mulheres passarem baldes, não dizemos **umas aos outros*.

Comment: Concordo. Curiosamente ["el uno a la otra" parece ser aceite em castelhano](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/uno-a-otro-el-uno-al-otro-articulo/) e também já consegui encontrar ["uma ao outro" em português](https://books.google.pt/books?id=vPIqAQAAIAAJ&q=%22uma+ao+outro%22&dq=%22uma+ao+outro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi597n29tDJAhUDMhoKHYj0D_MQ6AEIXDAJ)

Comment: @Jacinto No Google Books parece haver três exemplos onde há indiscutivelmente reciprocidade, e [um deles é claramente um erro](https://books.google.pt/books?id=iTbGAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&dq=%22uma+ao+outro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5_ZXxg9HJAhVH7g4KHUILBBUQ6AEIXTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22uma%20ao%20outro%22&f=false). Espero que fique por aqui, porque não me parece fazer sentido...